# Stale state value in use effect closure

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have an axios interceptor setup that reads from my auth context state and passes along that value to each request. The problem is the state value inside the interceptor function is always stale/the previous value. I cannot figure out for the life of me why this value is stale and how to get the current state value passed to the interceptor.

```
const { accounts } = useAuth();
const accountInterceptorRef = useRef(null);
....

useEffect(() => {
  if (accountInterceptorRef.current) {
    api.interceptors.request.eject(accountInterceptorRef.current);
  }
  console.log('Active Account Is: ', accounts.active); // <--- This always logs correct value
  const interceptor = api.interceptors.request.use(
    async (config) => {
      console.log('Active Account (closure) Is: ', accounts.active); // <--- This is always stale
      if (accounts.active) {
        config.params = config.params || {};
        config.params['user_account_id'] = accounts.active; // <--- This is always stale
      }
      return config;
    },
    (error) => Promise.reject(error)
  );
  accountInterceptorRef.current = interceptor;

}, [accounts.active]);
```

Again, my goal is to always pass the most up to date `accounts.active` value to the interceptor.

Comment: I'm not familiar with all the pieces so I can't say this is the best solution with 100% confidence, but I believe the recommended approach here would be to mirror your state in a `ref`. You'd need a `useEffect` that listens to the state change and keeps the ref up-to-date, but the ref shouldn't go stale in the closure since it's a stable object reference who's `current` value can be updated any time.

Comment: I feel the need to add, this is almost never the right solution, but in rare use-cases it might be. This example from the documentation shows this pattern slightly altered with no `useEffect` https://react.dev/learn/referencing-values-with-refs#read-the-latest-state